# ¿Cómo redondear numero decimal al mas próximo?

Tags: android, float

Quisiera que me ayuden con algo que para mi se me hace complicado, lo que deseo hacer es redondear un número decimal al próximo sin importar nada:

Por ejemplo 1.02, con la función `Math.round`;

```
Math.round(1.02) //Valor = 1 [lo que deseo es obtener `2`]
```

Lo que yo quiero es que el valor se redondee al próximo valor sin importar si el decimal es menor .5.

Comment: Has probado con la función `Math.ceil(1.02) // Valor = 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy sencillo solo basta con cambiar tu función Math.round(1.02), por la función **Math.ceil**(1.02) que redondea un número hacia arriba a su entero más cercano.

Answer (score 1):

En caso de redondear al valor más próximo superior:

- `Math.ceil(1.02); // 2`

En caso de redondear al inferior:

- `Math.floor(1.02); // 1`